# How to use telerik controls in asp.net

Tags: telerik

I am new for telerik controls, and i am too much confused about these controls how to use these controls in my asp.net site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a licensed verison of the controls, this should get you started: [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Step-by-Step tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/documents/RadControlsAJAXCourseware.pdf).

Also, Telerik (in addition to StackOverflow) has a terrific community that will help answer questions on [their forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx).

Don't forget to check out their [Documentation and Tutorials](http://www.telerik.com/support/documentation-and-tutorials.aspx) page.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to [download](http://www.telerik.com/download.aspx) telerik kit, from its website, it will give you trial version for short period. You will have to then install that kit, and then add its dll file in the toolbox through choose items, and its control will then appear in the toolbox, you might have to close visual studio and again restart it ,contorls to appear in toolbox. and then just drag and drop the control you want. If you want full version, you will have to buy kit of telerik, then you will get licensed telerik controls.

Answer (score 1):

the above answers as true, but as a simple soultion one u have purchased the telerik licence you can just

1) Reference the Telerik.Web.UI, Telerik.Web.UI.Skins and Telerik.Web.Desgin in your project and thats it ,( that's exactly what I'm doing in my current Project) ,

2)after you added those references now you have to register the telerik library in your page like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

3) add telerik controls using tags like this example:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="pnlControlsall" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true" EnableAjaxSkinRendering="true" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" >
```

thanks and I hope this helps as I have transferred my real working procedure to you here

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy , don't be confuse of telerik components..

Two basic things to keep in mind are , 
 - add references of telerik dll's in your application. 
 - and use events of telerik controls accoring to need , for e.g. radtree view has various events like nodeNeeded, MouseDoubleClick etc.

Telerik components are fun ! Enjoy..